# Is it possible to make John the Ripper work with only those entries that are in a wordlist (e.g. rockyou.txt)?

Tags: passwords

I don't want any mangling to be performed on the wordlist.

Comment: This is laid out in the John the Ripper documentation at http://www.openwall.com/john/doc/RULES.shtml - read the Simple Commands section

Comment: I'm voting to close this because your issue is with usage of terminal programs, not security specifically. As noted in all other reactions, please read at least the top part of the output of `man [command]` (man john in this case) before posing it as a question,

Comment: yes it is an OOB feature

Answer (score 0):

If you are using kali Linux then  you can  invoke john with the following command .

```
john --wordlist=/usr/share/wordlists/rockyou.txt /{path to hash file}
```

Suggest you to go through the documentations of john openwall.com/john/doc/RULES.shtml for other additional conditions like specifying the format , type single or multiple etc. 
There are many blog posts on the internet that provide a walkthrough.
Anyways the above command is the answer to your question.

Comment: the only dependancy on Kali is the specific location of that specific wordlist - you could make your answer more general by simply making the file location a variable, like you did with the other file location